# Instalar pip con idle

Tags: python

llevo un tiempo preguntándome si hay posibilidad de instalar librerías desde un mismo IDLE, osea tipo:

```
import pip  
pip.install("asciimatics")
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, pero no está diseñado para ser usado de ese modo, por lo que la interfaz (esto es, la forma de lanzarlo desde un script) puede cambiar según qué versión de python y pip tengas.

Para empezar, `pip` es un módulo Python sólo a partir de Python 3.4, antes era un ejecutable a instalar separadamente. Por otro lado, hay distribuciones de python que no lo incluyen. Finalmente, parece que el módulo `pip` que importas cuando haces `import pip` es diferente según estés dentro de un entorno virtual o no.

Dicho todo esto, he conseguido que lo siguiente funcione (pero bien podría dejar de funcionar en otra versión).

- Operativo: OSX
- Python 3.6.4
- Entorno virtual creado con `python -m venv ejemplo`
- y activado con `source ejemplo/bin/activate`

Ejemplo que instala el paquete `asciimatics` desde un script python:

```py
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'asciimatics'])
```

El mismo script funciona también en:

- Operativo: Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- Python: 3.5.2 (`/usr/bin/python3`)
- Sin entorno virtual (instalación global)

Pero el mismo script, incluso en el mismo operativo y misma versión de python, ya no funciona si se está en un entorno virtual creado con `virtualenv`, es decir:

- Sistema Operativo: Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- Python: 3.5.2 (`/usr/bin/python3`)
- Entorno virtual creado con: `virtualenv --python=python3 ejemplo`
- y activado con: `source ejemplo/bin/activate`

Para que funcione en este caso hay que usar esto otro:

```
import pip
from pip._internal import main as pip_main
pip_main(['install', 'asciimatics'])
```

En resumen, no me parece una vía muy recomendable. Igual es más portable un simple:

```
import os
os.system("pip install asciimatics")
```